# - error TypeError [ERR_INVALID_URL]: Invalid URL in production Nextjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, production, next.js13

error TypeError [ERR_INVALID_URL]: Invalid URL     at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)     at URL.onParseError (node:internal/url:565:9)     at new URL (node:internal/url:645:5)     at new URL (node:internal/url:642:22)     at NextRequestAdapter.fromNodeNextRequest (/home/yavarnet/nodevenv

When I take the build from the project and hit npm start, it works fine, but when I upload it to the host, it gives this error when the user logs in.

thank you

error TypeError [ERR_INVALID_URL]: Invalid URL     at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)     at URL.onParseError (node:internal/url:565:9)     at new URL (node:internal/url:645:5)     at new URL (node:internal/url:642:22)     at NextRequestAdapter.fromNodeNextRequest (/home/yavarnet/nodevenv

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.